# Writing a static method in Java to return a string using loops

Tags: java, loops, methods

The full assignment is:

Write two public classes (named exactly), TextBox and TextBoxTester.  TextBox contains the following overloaded static methods called textBoxString.  This method returns a String value.

```
public static String textBoxString (int side)
```

The returned String value, when printed, displays as the outline of a square of side characters.  The character you use is up to you.  Don't forget that '\n' will force a newline character into the returned String.  For example, let's assume I want to use * as the character for my box:

```
     String s =  textBoxString(3); 

     System.out.println(s);
```

will print

```
xxx  
x x  
xxx
```

---

```
public static String textBoxString(int side, char bChar)
```

The returned String value, when printed, displays the outline of a square of side characters using bChar as the box character.  For example,

```
     String s = textBoxString(4, '+'); 

     System.out.println(s);
```

will print

```
++++   
+  +  
+  +  
++++
```

So far, this is what I have:

```
public class TextBox {

    public static String textBoxString(int side) {
        int n = side;
        String string = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == n - 1) {
                string = "***";
            }
            else {
                string = "*    *";
            }
        }
        return string;

    }

    public static String textBoxString(int side, char bChar) {
        int n = side;
        char c = bChar;
        String string = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == n -1) {
                string = c + " " + c + " " + c + " " + c;
            }
            else {
                string = c + "      " + c;
            }
        }
        return string;
    }
}
```

My issue is returning the result. I don't know how to return the result that I need, that I would get from running this in a main method (for the first method):

```
int n = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == 0 || i == n - 1) {
        System.out.println("***");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("*  *");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

To make `textBoxString` work for varying values for `side`, you cannot use the hardcoded string `"***"` because that will only work when `side` equals 3.

You'll need to use nested loops to accomplish this.

I'm not gonna write the complete code for you, but I'm gonna give you a hint.

```
if (i == 0 || i == n - 1) {
    // Use a for loop here to construct the top and bottom rows
}
else {
    string = "*    *";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You have done the same mistake which Derek Yang has done. The number of space should depend on `int side` whereas you have used `*    *` which has a fixed number (`4`) of space.

Comment: He only hinted the first line. The `string="*    *";` is copied. It's a hint. If he were to fix that as well, it'd be a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested loops to achieve this.

```
public static String textBoxString(int n, char c) {
 String output = "";
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // constructing all rows
  output += c;
  for(int j = 1; j < n-1; j++) { // constructing a single row
     if(i == 0 || i == n - 1)
       output += " " + c; // use character to fill up each element in the row
     else
       output += " "; // use space to fill up
  }
  output += " " + c +"\n";
 }
return output;
}
```

Run and print

```
x x x x x
x       x
x       x
x       x
x x x x x
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add "\n" to your string, it will start a new line.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == n -1) {
            string += c + " " + c + " " + c + " " + c + "\n";
        }
        else {
            string += c + "      " + c + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

After adding that in, return string

Comment: Wow, I totally forgot about += as well. Thank you!

Comment: This is not the correct way to do it. It will always print a fixed number of spaces. The number of space should depend on `int side`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String textBoxString(int side) {
        int n = side;
        String string = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == n - 1) {

                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    string += "*";
                }
                string += "\n";
            } else {
                string += "*";
                for (int j = 1; j < n - 1; j++) {

                    string += " ";
                }

                string += "*\n";
            }
        }
        return string;

    }
```

Comment: Instead of just dumping a bunch of code on OP, you might want to clarify where he/she could imrpove. This answer is not explaining anything.